# String comparison is not equal when it should be

Tags: java, android, string, equals

I have a function that tries to get data from a JSON file that my application manages. In this function, I need to get the data of the JSON file so then I can convert them to objects using GSON. So for example, if i have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "test": [
        {"id":1,"insider":false,"name":"Name"}
    ]
}
```

I want my function to ONLY get:

```
        {"id":1,"insider":false,"name":"Name"}
```

Here there is the function:

```
private static final String open = "{\n";
private static final String start = "    \"test\": [\n";
private String data = null;
private static final String end = "    ]\n";
private static final String close = "}";

public void getFileUser() {
    Log.i("Console","getFileUser");
    FileInputStream fin;
    String receiveString;
    boolean copy = false;
    boolean finish = false;
    try {
        fin = context.openFileInput(TEST_FILE);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin, "UTF-8"), 1024);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("Console", receiveString);
            // Log.i("Console", start);
            // Log.i("Console", end);
            if (receiveString.equals(start)) {
                Log.i("Console", "BEGIN");
                copy = true;
            }
            if (receiveString.equals(end)) {
                Log.i("Console", "END");
                finish = true;
            }
            if (copy && !finish) stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
        }
        fin.close();
        data = new String(String.valueOf(stringBuilder).getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        Log.i("Console",data);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { Log.i("Console", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage()); }
    catch (IOException e) { Log.i("Console", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage()); }
    catch (Exception e) { Log.i("Console", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage()); }
}
```

In theory, the function I made supposedly should accomplish my goal but BOTH of the if conditions never become true, so my String data which should contain what I want is empty.

I believe the problem is something about new lines and spaces in the String but I have tried and have not been able to fix it.

Here there is the function that stores the JSON file since some users have requested it:

```
private static final String open = "{\n";
private static final String start = "    \"test\": [\n";
private String data = null;
private static final String end = "    ]\n";
private static final String close = "}";

public void setFileUser(String data) {
    Log.i("Console","setFileUser");
    FileOutputStream fOut;
    try {
        fOut = context.openFileOutput(TEST_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fOut.write(open.getBytes());
        fOut.write(start.getBytes());
        if (this.data != null) fOut.write(this.data.getBytes());
        String formatted_data = "        " + data + "\n";
        fOut.write(formatted_data.getBytes());
        fOut.write(end.getBytes());
        fOut.write(close.getBytes());
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

How I get String data since probably some people will ask for it:

```
    String data = rawResult.getText();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Test test = gson.fromJson(data, Test.class);
    Log.i("Console",  test.getName());
    Singleton.getInstance().setFileUser(data);
    Singleton.getInstance().getFileUser();
```

Both lines in the middle are to make sure that the string is properly formatted.

Comment: Use any JSON parser libs. They will do your job easily

Comment: Note that `readLine` does **not** return the end of line characters that ended the line (which is not one of the most brilliant design decisions imaginable of course, but there we are). I do think that matching against an explicit amount of whitespace is not a good idea. Short of using a parser (which is indeed probably the best idea) I'd consider regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to enter BOTH if conditionals thanks to @Maarten-reinstateMonica comment by making a copy of the String start and end and removing the last end of line. I had to make some other small changes in the class that managed this function but overall what I said above was what I needed.

The function is now like this:

```
private void getFile() {
    Log.i("Console","getFile");
    FileInputStream fin;
    String receiveString;
    String data;
    boolean copy = false;
    boolean finish = false;
    try {
        fin = context.openFileInput(TEST_FILE);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin, "UTF-8"), 1024);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String formatted_end = end.substring(0, end.length() - 1);
            if (receiveString.equals(formatted_end)) finish = true;
            if (copy && !finish) stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            String formatted_start = start.substring(0, start.length() - 1);
            if (receiveString.equals(formatted_start)) copy = true;
        }
        fin.close();
        data = new String(String.valueOf(stringBuilder).getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        this.loadList(data);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { Log.i("Console", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage()); }
    catch (IOException e) { Log.i("Console", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage()); }
    catch (Exception e) { Log.i("Console", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage()); }
}
```